# How to simulate barcode scan on Zebra device

Tags: barcode-scanner, motorola, motorola-emdk

I would like to simulate barcode scan request on Zebra device, (Device is using EMDK lib).
Is there any instructions on how to do it.
I found only [`DataWedge` instructions](https://developer.zebra.com/community/home/blog/2018/12/20/testing-your-zebra-scanning-application-on-an-emulator) but looks like it's not suitable for `EMDK`.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a blog about how to do this a few years back (http://www.darryncampbell.co.uk/2017/03/01/instrumented-testing-and-the-zebra-emdk-barcode-api/) but I'm unsure if it would work with the latest emdk without modification. This is not officially supported which is why I put it on my personal website. Note I am the author of those datawedge instructions you linked, looks like I need to fix the formatting of that article!